# Access Windows 2008 Server through Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I just installed ubuntu 13.10 on a new laptop someone gave me, because I've always wanted to learn.  I've had an easy time so far, but I need to access my work's Windows 2008 Server.  I have scoured the internet for answers but haven't had any luck.  I can access it using Remote Desktop Connection with any windows, but not Ubuntu.

All i know is that (on windows) the computer is heartland.zapto.org

I don't know server IP's or anything

Comment: how you want to connect without knowing th ip !

Comment: All i know is how to connect using windows rdc.  I never have to put in a IP, i just have to type heartland.zapto.org where it says computer.  My employer using a company that owns the server.

Answer (score 0):

Drop to a terminal window and do

> apt-get install rdesktop

To connect to the office windows systems, type the following command at a shell prompt

> rdesktop heartland.zapto.org

Comment: It says:  Autoselected keyboard map en-us